# Why doesn't jquery validation plugin's remote attribute work for me?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, attributes

I use jquery validation plugin and the remote attribute works with emailId but not with mobileNo?

```
var validator = $("#addform").validate({
    rules: {
    Name: "required",
    MobileNo: {
             required: true,
           minlength: 10, remote: '<%=Url.Action("getClientMobNo", "Clients") %>'
                },
                Address: "required"
              },
   messages: {
       Name: "please provide a client name",
       MobileNo: {
          required: "Please provide a mobile phone no",
          rangelength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
          remote: jQuery.format("This MobileNo is already in use")
        },
        Address: "please provide client address"
       },
```

A `null` value is passed to my controller action.. Any suggestion...

```
    public JsonResult getClientMobNo(string mobno)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        string status = clirep.getClientMobNo(Convert.ToInt64(mobno));
        if (status == "Mobile No already exists")
        {
            result.Data = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Data = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable names aren't matching up.  JQuery is passing a parameter of MobileNo, but your function is looking for mobno.  Change your function to accept the parameter MobileNo, and you'll get your value.

```
public JsonResult getClientMobNo(string MobileNo)
{
```